# Error while converting json to struct from Go

Tags: mysql, go, gorilla, mux

```
 func MakeMap(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // userInfo := context.Get(r, "userInfo").(model.User)
    type _getData struct {
        Title string   `json:"title"`
        Tag   []string `json:"tag"`
    }
    var getData _getData
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&getData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Print(getData)

}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error

```
2021/08/24 13:56:54 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:50619: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 23 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0x140001e9180)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1824 +0x108
panic(0x10505b860, 0x10522f240)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:971 +0x3f4
traveling/controller/mapController.MakeMap(0x1050b5630, 0x140001f40e0, 0x1400018aa00)
/Users/choeyunseog/traveling/traveling/controller/mapController/mapController.go:20 +0x3c
```

I've just started studying, I'm not sure why I'm having this problem, please help

[image]

```
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&getData)
```

I get the following error when i change code line 20 like above

```
 2021/08/24 14:16:44 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:51396: invalid character '-' in numeric literal
goroutine 23 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0x140001e9360)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1824 +0x108
panic(0x100d85d00, 0x14000206070)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:971 +0x3f4
traveling/controller/mapController.MakeMap(0x100df1630, 0x140001f40e0, 0x1400018aa00)
        /Users/choeyunseog/traveling/traveling/controller/mapController/mapController.go:24 +0x194
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x100de75d8, 0x100df1630, 0x140001f40e0, 0x1400018aa00)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x40
```

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected what you said

Comment: Can you print `w`, `r` and update the question

Comment: Postman shows that you are passing `form-data` yet you try to parse the body as json.

Comment: As you said, I changed the code, but the result is empty

Comment: Why am I not receiving the data sent from Postman?

Comment: Because you are NOT sending JSON. You are sending `form-data`. JSON and form-data are not one and the same thing.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much, sorry, is there any other way to receive form-data in golang?? What method should I use when I want to check form-data?

Comment: I use it like tag[] in postman, but I don't know how to get this array from golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the multipart form data from a POST/PUT/PATCH request's body you can use the [`ParseMultipartForm`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17#Request.ParseMultipartForm) method to parse the body and then access the data through the [`PostForm`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17#Request.PostForm) field. Or you can use [`FormValue`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17#Request.FormValue) to get just the first value associated with the form's field.

```golang
maxMemory := 32<<20
if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(maxMemory); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(_getData{
    Title: r.FormValue("title"), // FormValue returns string
    Tag:   r.PostForm["tag[]"],  // PostForm is a map of []string
})
```

Comment: i try 

 type _getData struct {
  Title string   `json:"title"`
  Tag   []string `json:"tag"`
 }
 var getData _getData

 getData.Tag = r.FormValue("tag[]")

and get error like this


cannot use r.FormValue("tag[]") (value of type string) as []string value in assignment

Comment: I know, what I want is, when sending multiple pieces of information like tag[] in postman, I wonder how to receive this data as an array in golang

Comment: Thanks, all problems are solved, but

var getData _getData

getData.Tag = r.PostForm["tag[]"]
getData.Title = r.FormValue("title")

When I use it like below, I do not receive an array value, what is the reason?

Comment: I didn't write about r.ParseForm(), I'm really sorry but can you show me a simple example of how r.ParseForm() should be used I'm really sorry

Comment: type _getData struct {
  Title string   `json:"title"`
  Tag   []string `json:"tag"`
 }
 if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
  panic(err)
 }

 var getData _getData
 getData.Tag = r.PostForm["tag[]"]
 getData.Title = r.FormValue("title")
 fmt.Print(getData)

Comment: I wrote the above

the result is still

{ []}

is

Comment: @Choiyunseok my mistake, I mixed up `multipart/form-data` with `form-urlencoded`. See updated answer.

Comment: Everything worked out, thank you very much, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use to parse form data into json like annotated struct using package [github.com/senpathi/paramex](https://github.com/senpathi/paramex). Struct fields must be annotated with `param` keyword and tag name is key of the form data.

your struct should be as below.

```
type _getData struct {
        Title string   `param:"title"`
        Tag   []string `param:"tag[]"`
    }
```

This is the updated MakeMap handler function for your postman request mentioned in the question

```
func MakeMap(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // userInfo := context.Get(r, "userInfo").(model.User)
    type _getData struct {
        Title string   `param:"title"`
        Tag   []string `param:"tag[]"`
    }

    // this needed because u send data from Postman as multipart/form-data
    maxMemory := 32<<20
    if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(int64(maxMemory)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var getData _getData

    extractor := paramex.NewParamExtractor()
    err := extractor.ExtractForms(&getData, r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Print(getData)
    //Output: {defaultMap [travelling travelling2]}
}
```